# Firebase snapshot retrieving multiple elements when child added

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, option-type

I am trying to write a messaging app with Swift and Firebase, which appears to run smoothly 75% of the time, but crashes every so often because multiple messages are pulled in as a snapshot instead of just one.

I added print statements to my code to print the snapshot in question and here's the code and console outputs:

Here's the code:

```
 private func observeMessages() {

    let messagesQuery = messageReference!.queryLimitedToLast(25)

    messagesQuery.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {snapshot in


        print(snapshot.value)
        print(snapshot.value!["senderId"])

        let id = snapshot.value?["senderId"] as! String 
        let text = snapshot.value?["text"] as! String


        self.addMessage(id, text: text)


        self.finishReceivingMessage()
    })
}
```

An output from the console when it runs smoothly:

```
Optional({
senderId = mVHbzSGdSIS4mIkeprRWZtKtdow2;
text = Did;
}) //Print statement for snapshot.value!
Optional(mVHbzSGdSIS4mIkeprRWZtKtdow2) 
//Print statement for snapshot.value!["senderId"]
```

And the output from the console when it errors:

```
Optional({
"-KLSJznUSC_alQSoTP9G" =     {
    senderId = mVHbzSGdSIS4mIkeprRWZtKtdow2;
    text = Test;
};
"-KLSK1fTfCBXsCp9Flul" =     {
    senderId = mVHbzSGdSIS4mIkeprRWZtKtdow2;
    text = Test;
};
})   //Print statement for snapshot.value!
nil //Print statement for snapshot.value!["senderId"]
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

As you can see, when the code fails, the snapshot seems to be pulling in two different messages instead of one, and I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

**UPDATE — See below for the code block that adds data to Firebase:**

```
override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {

    let itemRef = messageReference!.childByAutoId()
    let messageItem = [
        "text": text,
        "senderId": senderId
    ]
    itemRef.setValue(messageItem)

    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

    finishSendingMessage()
}
```

Comment: can you post how you insert in to firebase ...

Comment: yep, see main post for update.